# Dynamic graphs at ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to develop report at SSRS include pie chart, that based on dataset (the dataset can change every day)
Can I make "dynamic pie" on report that change the number of graphs according to the dataset I define?
[A particular day can have 2 employees (2 pie graphs) and another day can have 5 or more employees (and therefore need 5 different graphs)]
For example:
This is the report that I need, based on this dataset 
[Requested report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nmWp.png)
[My_Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNtnS.png)
Thank!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a brief overview of the main steps...

You will need two reports.

The first will be a subreport. So build a report that takes one or more parameters, based on your sample data the parameter would be Emp_Name. Build this report that it can handle a single employee only. The dataset might be something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Emp_Name = @Emp_Name`

Once that is complete, create a second report. Add a dataset that contains just a list of the employees so something like `SELECT DISTINCT Emp_name FROM myTable ORDER BY Emp_Name`

Add a list or table to this report and set the dataset to the dataset you just created. In the list (or table) right-click inside the cell and "insert => Subreport". Set the subreport to be the first report you created. and the parameter to be the EMp_Name field from your dataset.

When you run the seconds report it will create one row in the list for each employee in the dataset, inside each row it will run your subreport and pass the respective paramater.

That's it really.

Note that this will produce a vertical list but it should get you started. There are plenty of examples of how to arrange horizontally.